# Getting Unique Numbers and Knowing When They're Freed

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, numbers

I have a physics simulation (using Box2D) where bodies with identical integer IDs do not collide, for instance, bodies that belong to the same character.  I have a problem though in that I need to be able to get a unique number for each possible entity, so that no two characters accidentally get the same ID.  There's a finite number of bodies, but they are created and destroyed as the simulation dictates, so it's necessary to free unique IDs once the body they belonged to is gone.

A class `World` is responsible for creating and destroying all bodies, and is also the entity that manages the unique number generation, and anything else where physics simulation is concerned.

I thought of two methods so far but I'm not sure which would be better, if either of them at all:

- Keep a `vector<short>`, with the data being the number of references floating around, and the position in the vector being the ID itself.  This method has the disadvantage of creating unneeded complexity when coding entities that manipulate group IDs, since they would need to ensure they tell the `World` how many references they're taking out.
- Keep a `vector<bool>`, with the data being if that ID is free or not, and the position in the vector being the ID itself.  The vector would grow with every new call for a unique ID, if there exist no free slots.  The disadvantage is that once the vector reaches a certain size, an audit of the entire simulation would need to be done, but has the advantage of entities being able to grab unique numbers without having to help manage reference counting.

What do you folks think, is there a better way?

Comment: Is there a single object per body? In that case you could just compare the addresses of the objects.

Comment: Each body has one or more 'shape' primitives attached to it, which have their own filter ID, so a body may have more than one.  I like the idea of using the addresses, but the filter data is stored as a negative `short`, (positive IDs actually mean something entirely different, which is to always collide with similarly ID'd shapes no matter what)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could maintain a "free" list of unused IDs as a singly linked list inside your master `World` object.

When an object is destroyed by `World` (making its ID unused) you could push that ID onto the head of the free list.

When you are creating a new object you could do the following:

```
If the free list is non-empty: pop the head item and take that ID.
Else increment a global ID counter and assign it's current value.
```

While you could still run out of IDs (if you simultaneously had more objects than the max value of your counter), this strategy will allow you to recycle IDs, and to do everything with `O(1)` runtime complexity.

EDIT: As per @Matthieu's comments below, a `std::deque` container could also be used to maintain the "free" list. This container also supports the `push_front, pop_front` operations with `O(1)` complexity .

Hope this helps.

Comment: ... That's brilliant.  I am ashamed I didn't consider a linked list until now.

Comment: Wouldn't you also need some sort of reference counting mechanism? How do you know when an ID becomes unused?

Comment: @Miguel Grinberg I assume when `World` destroys the object it will also add the ID back to the list (also assuming `World` is maintaining the list to begin with)

Comment: @Miguel, ssell: Yes exactly. When an object is destroyed (by World) it's ID is pushed onto the free list to be recycled .

Comment: @Clairvoire: It's nice to be able to find a genuine use for a linked-list!

Comment: @Clairvoire, Darren: not wanting to be a party poop but... you're using the linked-list as a stack. And stack are better implemented with `deque` for better memory requirements, which might in turn lead to better caching behavior.

Comment: @Matthieu - those are even better!  The best part, was how all I had to change was one `std::list` to `std::deque` and it still works.  :P

Comment: @Matthieu: Agreed - you could use a `std::deque` instead of a list. On the upside, the `pop_front` operation for a singly linked-list is very simple (and fast), on the downside the extra space per list node for the pointers is a (big) negative. I would benchmark and take the best container in practice...

Comment: @Clairvoire: to make the intent even clearer you could actually use the Container Adapter `stack` over a `deque` (actually the default) by switching to `std::stack`. If you were using `*_front` operations you would have to change them to `*_back` though.

Comment: @Darren: Actually, pop and push are likely to be faster on a `deque`, as there is less book-keeping to be done. I do subscribe to the benchmark idea, but I guess the speed difference would not be very significant in the OP case --> it's pretty insignificant in face of collision detection.

Answer (score 4):

How many bodies are there? Is it realistic that you'd ever run out of integers if you didn't reassign them? The simplest solution is to just have one integer storing the next ID -- you would increment this integer when you assign a new ID to a body.

Comment: I agree this would be the best as long as @Clairvoire is not expecting to use more than the max value of an `unsigned`. Even then, using a `long long` would work.

Comment: @ssell:  a `float` or `double` makes the situation worse.  Stick to integers.  If more than 2^32 is needed, use a `long long` or whatever the 64-bit integer data type is for your environment.

Comment: @wallyk Yea, I was just about to edit my comment to use `long long` instead. But glad you mentioned it!

Comment: If you were using up an ID 30 times a second, it would take over 2 years to overflow a 31-bit integer.

Comment: The IDs themselves are stored as `short`.  My main worry with this, is that as the simulation goes on, it may cause the integer we're incrementing to overflow back to 0, and if a very old object with a low ID still exists, it may find another recently created object with the same ID and thus not be able to collide with it

Comment: I should probably add, the decision to use `short` here was not mine.  I am using box2D for physics.  Just goin' with what's given.

Comment: @ssell - no, I agree.  It's open source, so I might as well change it to suit my needs.  Strawman and all that~